# nvmctray.dll and then daemonu.exe trying to access Internet on startup?

Tags: windows-xp, graphics-card, firewall, nvidia-geforce

When I start-up my PC, Comodo Firewall 5.4.189822.1355 shows an alert that this is trying to access the Internet:

```
Application:
nvmctray.dll

Remote:
127.0.0.1 - TCP

Port:
2559

Shortly, afterwards, I receive a further Internet access alert:

Application:
daemonu.exe

Remote:
127.0.0.1 - TCP

Port:
48001
```

I believe these are relating to the NVIDIA graphics card drivers.

However, why are these applications trying to access the Internet?  I have disabled auto updates in NIVIDIA settings, so I can't see any reason why NVIDIA would need to access the Internet.

As a precaution, I have tried a virus/spyware scan and all is reported fine.

I am using Windows XP Home SP 3.  Graphics - NVIDIA GeForce 6100 nForce 405 with version 275.33 of drivers.

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is not the internet, don't disable them...http://what-is-what.com/what_is/127.0.0.1.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the instructions [in this article](http://www.ghacks.net/2011/03/31/nvidia-update-3d-vision-controller-new-nvidia-graphics-driver-components/) and it should solve your problem. Note: while this article suggests changing the service type to **Disabled**, I suggest going with **Manual**.

Comment: Nice article - thanks.  I set the NVIDIA update service to Manual in services, and in startup disabled NVIDIA control panel.  Now I don't get any Comodo alerts (even though the alerts were for 127.0.0.1 localhost - as @Moab mentions).